# In-Loop Assignment of Array Elements question -- why is one of my variables incorrect?

Tags: arrays, pine-script, variable-assignment, pine-script-v5

How come y≠x=z?

```
//@version=5

// I'M TESTING THIS CODE IN 1MIN TIMEFRAME

indicator("xyz")

x=array.new_float(2,na)
y=array.new_float(2,na)
z=array.new_float(2,na)

x.set(0,request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"5",close))
x.set(1,request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"6",close))

for i=0 to 1
    y.set(i,x.get(i)[i+5])
    if i==0
        z.set(i,x.get(i)[i+5])
    else if i==1
        z.set(i,x.get(i)[i+5])

plot(x.get(0)[5],color=color.red)
plot(y.get(0),color=color.green)
plot(z.get(0),color=color.blue)
```

All three plots should be identical. But the one I need (y) comes out incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, this is one weird error and probably needs further investigation.

While testing, I found that the following code gives all three plots as same, even if it actually **shouldn't**:

```
int i = 0

while i < 1 // shouldn't work as i == 1 should exit the loop
    y.set(i, x.get(i)[i+5])
    z.set(i,x.get(i)[i+5])
    i := i + 1
```

I don't know if it is just me, or if there is something weird going on.

Answer (score 0):

The official response from TradingView reads:

"The loop will execute the code block multiple times on the same bar, note that the variables are committed on the bar's close after all iterations of the loop. As is mentioned in the warning message - "So, obtaining its historical values may lead to unexpected results", only the last committed value can be referenced on historical bars."

So, this is a hopeless endeavor for now.